# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I wrote this code from a book in order to practise. However, when I tried to run it, it didn't work and I keep having the same error "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not reader". It would be nice and friendly if you guys could check it out and tell me, what went wrong. I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

```
import csv
ruta = open(r"C:\Users\ronald\Documents\PYTHON DATA\importes.csv")
ruta = csv.reader(ruta)

with open(ruta, encoding='latin1') as fichero_csv:
    lector = csv.reader(fichero_csv)
    next(lector, None)
    importe_total = 0
    for linea in lector:
       importe_str = linea [2]
       importe = float(importe_str)
       importe_total = importe_total + importe
    print(importe_total)
```

Comment: `with open(ruta,` - `ruta` here is a CSV reader, not a path. It's already open and ready for usage.

Comment: Try to remove the first `ruta = csv.reader(ruta)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `open()` twice. Just call it once, with the filename as the argument, in the `with` statement.

```
with open(r"C:\Users\ronald\Documents\PYTHON DATA\importes.csv", encoding='latin1') as fichero_csv:
    lector = csv.reader(fichero_csv)
    next(lector, None)
    importe_total = 0
    for linea in lector:
       importe_str = linea [2]
       importe = float(importe_str)
       importe_total = importe_total + importe
    print(importe_total)
```